# Returning a string from a Future's callback function

Tags: flutter

I think this should be easy but I am pretty confused. I want to return 'result' from the callback function of Future.delay and I don't know why it is throwing an error of 'The non-nullable local variable 'result' must be assigned before it can be used' meanwhile there is no error on the course material I am using. below is the code.

```
String task2(){

Duration three = Duration(seconds: 3);
String result;

Future.delayed(three, (){
result = 'task 2 data';
print('task 2 complete');
});

return result;

}
```

"result" in "return result" is the error here.

Comment: initilize your string `String result = "";`

Comment: use the `late` for that variable

Comment: @JahidulIslam that will return "result" as an empty string if I am to call out task2() but I want the function to return "result" as "task 2 complete" just as I initialized it in the callback function

Comment: you found an empty string because after 3 second you need to rebuild your UI

Comment: nope, i found an empty string because above in your code result is initialized with an empty string, looks like the initialization of result in the callback function is not recognized. why is that? @JahidulIslam

Comment: @Caffo17 adding late to the variable removed the error, but result still did not return the initialization in the callback function

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't return a `String` from a function where the content of that `String` comes from a `Future`. What you could do is the following:

```
void main() async {
  final result = await task2();
  print(result);
}

Future<String> task2() {
  Duration three = Duration(seconds: 3);
  return Future.delayed(three, () {
    print('task 2 complete');
    return 'task 2 data';
  });
}
```